# Trouble enabling datetime_select with jQuery in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

and thank you for your support.  I'm trying to get a checkbox to enable a datetime_select field, not finding any success on my own.  I don't know javascript very well. I've just been adapting other answers to fit my situation. It isn't going well. Please help.

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :texture_date, "Texture" %>
    <%= f.datetime_select( :texture_date, 
{ :order => [:month, :day], :discard_hour => true, :discard_minute => true, disabled: true }, 
{ class: 'texture_date' }) %>
    <%= check_box_tag :texture_date_enable, '' %>
  </div>
.
.
.

<script type="text/javascript">
  var update_select = function () {
      if ($("#texture_date_enable").is(":checked")) {
          $(".texture_date select").removeAttr("disabled");
      }
      else {
          $(".texture_date select").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      }
  };

  update_select();
  $("#texture_date_enable").change(update_select);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`datetime_select` generates five select items, all with the class passed through the options. This means, that selector:

```
$(".texture_date select")
```

will not match any elemnets. It matches all selects within elements with `.texture_date` class. `.texture_date` elements  are selects on their own, so they have no select children.

Instead of this selector try using:

```
$("select.texture_date")
```

Comment: I still couldn't get it working, but I found something similar. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X5rRj/8/)

Comment: The field is disabled when the page loads. If the check_box is checked, then I want to enable the field. I think the code in my question might be misleading.

Comment: I got it!  With your help and from another question: $(document).on('change','#texture_date_enable',function(){  
  // use checkboxes to enable some datetime_select fields

    $("select.texture_date").prop('disabled', !this.checked);
  
});